# Read data from web service android (Azure website)

Tags: android, web-services, azure

I try to make an Android application. And i need read data from webservice for this app. Actually it have to very simple i know it. But somehow my app couldn't read any data from web service.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader bf = null;
        URL url;

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();

            bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
            }

            content = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bf.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And i try to read data from [this site](http://tcm-test-api.azurewebsites.net/api/movie/search?term=%22Batman%22&page=1)

Thanks for helping from now.

Comment: "This site" URL provides `<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>` as a response. Is the URL correct?

Comment: It's a data JSON formatted.